# Hoeffding's inequality vs DKW inequality

Tags: probability-inequalities

What is the difference between Hoeffding's inequality:
$$\mathrm{P}(|\hat{F}_n(x)-F(x)|\geq \epsilon) \leq 2e^{-2n\epsilon^2}$$
and the Dvoretzky-Kiefer-Wolfowith (DKW) inequality:
$$\mathrm{P}(\mathrm{sup}_{x \in \mathrm{r}}|\hat{F}_n(x)-F(x)|\geq \epsilon) \leq 2e^{-2n\epsilon^2}$$
where $F$ is the CDF.

It looks like the former is used to construct confidence intervals, while the later is used to construct confidence bands [(source)](https://www.win.tue.nl/~rmcastro/AppStat2013/files/lecture1.pdf).